# Last Listview item removed instead of selected one

Tags: java, android, listview, custom-adapter, items

I have a listView, with items.
When I longClick on one of them, a delete button appears. But when I press it, it's the last item which is deleted and not the one I pressed ...

Here my code :

```
appList0 = new ArrayList<Appreciation>();
String[] app0 = settings.getString("App0", "aucune remarque").toString().split(";");          
for (String app : app0) 
    appList0.add(new Appreciation(app));
dataAdapter0 = new MyCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.affichageitem, appList0);
ListView listView0 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView0);
listView0.setAdapter(dataAdapter0);
```

and the adapter

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Appreciation> {

          private ArrayList<Appreciation> appList;

          public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<Appreciation> appList) {
              super(context, textViewResourceId, appList);
              this.appList = new ArrayList<Appreciation>();
              this.appList.addAll(appList);
          }

          private class ViewHolder {
           TextView text;
           ImageButton button;
          }

          @Override
          public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

              ViewHolder holder=null;
              LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

               if (convertView == null) {                              
                   convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.affichageitem, null);                
                   holder = new ViewHolder();
                   holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
                   holder.button = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editButton);
                   convertView.setTag(holder);
               }
               else {
                   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                   holder.button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               }


               holder.text.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() { 
                     public void onClick(View v) { 
                          TextView tv = (TextView) v ; 
                          //To DO
                         } 
                }); 

               holder.button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() { 
                     public void onClick(View v) { 
                            ListView listView0=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView0); 

                            Log.e("DELETING : ",appList0.get(position).getValue());  
                            appList0.remove(position);   //DELETING HERE
                            dataAdapter0.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            ImageButton iB = (ImageButton) v ; 
                            iB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                     }          
                });

               holder.text.setOnLongClickListener( new View.OnLongClickListener() { 
                     public boolean onLongClick(View v) { 
                          TextView tv = (TextView) v ;
                          ImageButton editButton = (ImageButton) ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.editButton);
                          editButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          return true;
                         } 
                }); 

               Appreciation currentApp = appList.get(position);
               holder.text.setText(currentApp.getValue());
               holder.button.setTag(currentApp);          
               return convertView;

          }

         }
```

Comment: dose this Log.e("DELETING : ",appList0.get(position).getValue()); return valid element? i mean is it the element that you want to delete it?

Comment: Only the first time, and then there is a difference with one, two, etc items

Comment: i think i have found your bug, just try these few changes , i really really hope that it will fix it

Comment: where is the code that deletes the item from your `ArrayAdapter`?

Answer (score 1):

Since `getView()` runs for each item, you need to set a tag on the button so it can get the correct position.

Something like, before

```
// use position for the tag param
holder.button.setTag(position);
holder.button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
```

then retrieve the tag from the `View` that was clicked and use that

```
 holder.button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() { 
     public void onClick(View v) { 
     int position = ((Button)v).getTag();  // cast the view to Button and get the tag

      Log.e("DELETING : ",appList0.get(position).getValue());  
       appList0.remove(position);   //DELETING HERE
       dataAdapter0.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: when in getView he call findViewById , this function returns the button in the same row, there is no need for setting tag, and also the position is the row position

Comment: @mmlooloo of course he calls `findViewById()` the very first run through the method, you have to. But setting the position as the tag on each one should return that position when calling `getTag()` instead of always having the last position which is what is happening.

Comment: @codeMagic Thanks, but Adding int position = ((Button)v).getTag();
returns a Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to int

Comment: Yes, sorry, you need to cast the object.

Comment: Integer. On my phone or I'd give more details

Comment: And if I add :
ImageButton but = (ImageButton) v;
Log.e("HERE", String.valueOf(v.getTag()));
The returned value isn't the good one (16 instead of 14 for example)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some issues with using appList0 and appList. try these changes may help:

```
                    Log.e("DELETING : ",appList0.get(position).getValue());  
                    appList0.remove(position);   //DELETING HERE
                    dataAdapter0.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to

```
                    Log.e("DELETING : ",appList.get(position).getValue());  
                    appList.remove(position);   //DELETING HERE
                    MyCustomAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

change

```
      public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<Appreciation> appList) {
          super(context, textViewResourceId, appList);
          this.appList = new ArrayList<Appreciation>();
          this.appList.addAll(appList);
      }
```

to

```
      public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<Appreciation> appList) {
          super(context, textViewResourceId, appList);
          this.appList = appList;
      }
```

Comment: holder.button.this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); gives a 
"holder cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Cannot refer to a non-final variable holder inside an inner class defined in a different method :-(

Comment: very good just declare final Button b =  holder.button; and use b inside the onClick

Comment: declare that outside the setOnClick

Comment: Not better. The pb come from holder.button.setTag(position); When I call back with getTag(), I do not get an integer, but an object. How to cast it ?

Comment: i do not think that solves your problem, though use `Integer` class and use the methods and the constructors